# How to read files from directory by name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to read files in directory by name using interval `0-400`.
It means that programm reads files with names from 0 to 400.

Now I have this code:

```
 with open(file) as xml:
        doc = xmltodict.parse(xml.read())
```

So, I tried:

```
for num in range(0,400)
  filename = num".vtb"
  doc = xmltodict.parse(filename.read())
```

Problem is that I use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = glob.glob("data*")
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(open_xml, files)
    c.close()
```

I pass array `files` to `map` function. How can I pass `0-400` array files instead that?

Comment: What is happening right now that is not meeting your expectation. Explain the problem you are currently having. If you are getting any errors, show the Traceback.

Comment: First, it should be `for num in range(0,400): filename = num + ".vtb". Second, you may want explained what you stuck with, or people do not know what to answer.

Comment: So, no I read files as: `files = glob.glob("data/*")` after I pass this result to `map`: `pool.map(open_xml, files)`. So, I need to get files from 0 to 400 and pass these to `map`

Comment: Your code is wrong. In Python 3, `num".vtb"` is not a legal syntax. You might want to write `num + ".vtb"` instead, but since `num` is an int, you must convert it into a string: `str(num) + ".vtb"`. Besides, what is your question? What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of what you're asking. But the code you tried to write does not work, and I presume you want to know how to make it work. So, you wrote:

```
for num in range(0,400)
  filename = num".vtb"
  doc = xmltodict.parse(filename.read())
```

Instead, try:

```
for num in range(0,400)
  filename = str(num) + ".vtb"
  doc = xmltodict.parse(filename.read())
```

If this does not do what you want, then your problem lies elsewhere.

**EDIT**

Reading your comment, what I understand is that you want to pass these `0` to `400` files to `map`. Then you just need to build a list containing all the paths to use:

```
filenames = []
for num in range(0,400)
    filenames.append(str(num) + ".vtb")
```

Then:

```
pool.map(open_xml, filenames)
```

Comment: @Goga Updated answer.

Comment: So, loop should be outside?

Comment: @Goga Outside of what? Just build the list and then run `map`.